# Raspberry Pi connected to wifi but can't ping google.com

Tags: pi-2

My Rpi seems to be connected to wi-fi properly and I can even browse sites on the browser, but whenever I try to ping google.com it doesn't respond. I don't know if this is the Rpi faulty or my connection's problem.

Thank you

Comment: It could be many things... DNS, firewalls, connection

Try `nslookup google.com` and see if it can resolve the domain name (*google.com*) to an IP address. If that fails then start looking at DNS, if it gives you a valid IP back then try `traceroute the_ip_you_got_from_nslookup`

Comment: What about pinging other sites?  I remember being told once that some sites won't allow pings for whatever security reason, maybe Google is one of those?

Comment: Google can be pinged, both IPv4 and IPv6. In fact, Android does some connectivity tests whenever joining a network by pinging certain Google servers.